Single episode or repeated event?

I will not bother her now when/while/that you are sleeping

It is a correct sentence. Either conjunction is used the same meaning remians. That is I won't bother her during her current state of being asleep. The clause after when/while/that refers to the currentt not habitual state of sleeping.

I won't bother her now when/while/that

Do we get the same meaning here with one differnce that presnt simple would imply a habitaul work not one happening right now. I kindly ask for some comments.

If you mean 'not necessarily right now', why do you include the word 'now'? (And it's regularly.)

@Kate Bunting  I meant something like "since you already work hard  I will make you happy now" here we see the action "working" is repeated in the present  and it isn't ongoing right now. I wanted to see if I can convey similar meaning with "when and while" not using "since"?

I know it is possible with the present continuous where the meaning of "I will make you happy now when/whille/since you are working hard" is pretty much the same. Just here impy that working is already ongoing right now.

You always work so hard, so I'll try to make you feel happy today.

Your question is contradictory.  You say  "Since I see them working nonstop I have decided to make them happy"  That means "I have decided to make them happy because they are working non-stop".  But you also say "during (not because)"....  So please clarify.  Is the hard-work the reason you will make them happy, or not?

@James K no I just want to say during what kind of time I will make them happy. Do 1 and 2 work then?

Okay, Please edit your question to make it clear.    Change the sentence that starts "Since I see them working...."

If they always work hard why do you need to specify that you are doing this while they are working hard? It's like "I am making soup while two plus two equals four". It might have some kind of deeper/poetic meaning but it's not normal.

You completely changed the examples, therefor nullifying the answers posted below. There are 5 spelling mistakes/typos, which shows low effort, and a carefree nonchalant attitude.

Anyone wanting to edit the question should also fix the spelling errors, not just add the missing words/verb in sentence 2.

I wouldn’t call your sentence 2 incorrect, but it is certainly not idiomatic. A somewhat similar sentence that is idiomatic is

I will watch the baby now while you get some sleep.

But in your version, now and when you work so hard present conflicting senses of exactly when and over what period the doing their best is being promised. And the situation with while you work so hard is similar.
In your sentence 1, the while along with the present progressive conveys that the assistance is being offered during the period of the hard working and will not necessarily extend beyond the hard working, whereas the when version conveys “at this time of your taxing labor.”

I meant something like "since you already work hard I will make you happy now" here we see the action "working" is repeated in the present and it isn't ongoing right now. I wanted to see if I can convey similar meaning with "when and while" not using "since"?

But neither when nor while is synonymous with either since or because. And what do you mean to convey by including the adverb now? Your intended meaning is not clear. In what sense does something like I will do my best to make you happy because you are [or have been] working so hard fail to express your meaning?

ok I get but still I am sure that someone works hard these days  and because of that I want to make them happy now. Would my examples with when and while work in that case?

No. Neither when nor while conveys any meaning of because in your example. If you are happy leaving the causal relationship between the listener’s hard work and the speaker’s promise implicit, then fine. Either way, though, you still have not clarified what purpose you have in including the now.  Do you truly mean that the offer applies at this precise moment? How is such precision about the timing of the assistance particularly important or relevant? Until your full meaning is clear, your question cannot be answered with any confidence.
